# plotLines label does not show up in Chrome but on firefox

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I come to you to talk about a problem already solved in javascript but not in R.
I use the package `highcharter`, under the version 0.5.0, to plot a bar chart and a vertical line on it. The issue is that the **label linked to the line does not show up** on my chrome browser while it does on the firefox one. I have seen this issue in pure `javascript`, but never in `R-highcharter`.

Do you have an idea ?

Here a reproductible example (working on firefox but not on Chrome then) :

```
require(highcharter)
require(data.table)

    Donnees <- data.table(y=c(10,20,30),name=c("A","B","C"))

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "bar",
           polar = FALSE) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories=Donnees[,name]
  ) %>%
  hc_yAxis( title = list(text = "Anything"),
           plotLines = list(list(
             value = 15,
             color = '#070070',
             width = 3,
             # zIndex = 4,
             label = list(text = "I want a label pls"
                          ,style = list( color = 'blue', fontWeight = 'bold' )
             )))) %>% 
  hc_add_series(Donnees)
```

Comment: Check this [Github issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8477) maybe your problem and the issue are related

Comment: Thanks @Core972, as I said the problem was already solved in javascript, the link you provide me is indeed an answer. But my issue is R related, in particular to the highcharter package

Comment: This issue is probably caused by R wrapper and older version of highcharts it is using. You can suggest the wrapper authors to update highcharts version where this bug is solved - https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter.

Comment: You're probably right Wojtek. What do you think about it @jbkunst  ?